# setMaxResults(max_size) throws Sql command not properly ended exception

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hql

I'm using the hibernate version 4.3.11.Final and 1.0.0.Final.
hibernate.dilect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect

```
final String hql1 = "select s from " + app.class.getSimpleName() + " s where s.Id = " + getId();
When i'm calling 
mEntityManager.createQuery(hql1, app.class).setMaxResults(3);
```

generated hql = "**select app_.ID as ID6_157_ from test.APP_TABLE app_ where app_.ID=83700 fetch first ? rows only**"

Problme that seems is '?' is not being replaced with value 3 of setMaxResults, But could not figure out how to fix it.
It's throwing the exception :-

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

 oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:445)
 oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
 oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:879)
 oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:450)
 oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:192)
 oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
 oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:207)
 oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:884)
 oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1167)
 oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1289)
 oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3584)
 oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3628)
 oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1493)
 com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52)
 com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:80)
 org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2065)
 org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1862)
 org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1838)
 org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:909)
 org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)
 org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2553)
 org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2539)
 org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2369)
 org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2364)
 org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:496)
 org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387)
 org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:231)
 org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1264)
 org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)
 org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:573)
 org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:449)
```

Query works fine, if i remove the setMaxResults(3) from the createQuery.

Any suggestions what could be the reason for this.

Comment: select app_.ID as ID6_157_ from test.APP_TABLE app_ where app_.ID=83700 fetch first ? rows only

Comment: This query has nothing to do with JPA. Why using wrong tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you every one for your responses.
I figured out the fix for my problem. 
I changed my hibernate dialect to "**org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect**" and my problem was fixed.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem doesn't come from the question mark. Hibernate will inject the parameter value when executing the query.

Moreover, you shouldn't create the query using string concatenation. It should be like

```
entityManager.createQuery("Select s from Apps s where s.id = :id")
 .setParameter(":id", id)
 .setMaxResults(3);
```

I think the problem is the table name test.APP_TABLE with the package name "test.". You can try to copy the generated query and run it directly in Oracle to see the result and find out what is the error.